ImportError: cannot import name 'CommitInfo' from 'huggingface_hub'
I am encountering an ImportError when running a Python script that imports CommitInfo from the huggingface_hub package. The error message is as follows:
ImportError: cannot import name 'CommitInfo' from 'huggingface_hub' (/home/user/anaconda3/envs/kg/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/__init__.py)

I have ensured that the huggingface_hub package is installed and up-to-date. Here is the full traceback of the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    import datasets
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/kg/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .arrow_dataset import Dataset
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/kg/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 63, in <module>
    from huggingface_hub import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'CommitInfo' from 'huggingface_hub' (/home/user/anaconda3/envs/kg/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/__init__.py)

I work on Ubuntu 24.04
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Checked the version of huggingface_hub:

python -c "import huggingface_hub; print(huggingface_hub.__version__)"


Upgraded huggingface_hub to the latest version:

pip install --upgrade huggingface_hub


Cleanly reinstalled huggingface_hub:

pip uninstall huggingface_hub
pip install huggingface_hub


Checked the import path to ensure there are no conflicts:

python -c "import huggingface_hub; print(huggingface_hub.__file__)"

I expected these steps to resolve the ImportError, but the issue persists. Any guidance on resolving this import error would be greatly appreciated.

Running the following command resolved my issue, but I don't know why.
conda install chardet

